# How To Detect When User Tapped Screen while displaying a document in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, xamarin, uidocumentinteraction

When I tapped the screen it looks like this

[image]

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController in xamarin.ios

But i need to find being full screen event. I mean, when i tapped the screen, it goes to the fullscreen mode but it doesnt hide navigationbar as you see in the picture. So if i can find that event i can hide the navigation bar, but exit fullscreen, i should also find it.

before i tried these but not working

```
    NavigationController.HidesBarsOnTap = true;
    NavigationController.HidesBarsOnSwipe = true;
```